# How to establish a WebSocket connection in android service?

Tags: java, android, websocket

I've been trying to create a android service which would allow me to maintain a websocket connection and send some data time to time. I create a handler in service to connect with the WebSocketClient. But it is not connecting. The url is working and I have tested it too. I highly appreciate if anyone can help.

Main Activity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BroadcastReceiver receiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            TextView text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            text.setText(intent.getStringExtra("msg"));

        }
    };

    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(SocketService.BROADCAST_ACTION));

    }


    // Method to start the service
    public void startService(View view) {
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), SocketService.class));
    }

    // Method to stop the service
    public void stopService(View view) {
        stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), SocketService.class));
    }



}
```

Service Implementation

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake;

import java.net.URI;

import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

public class SocketService extends Service {

    boolean status=false;
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.supun.broadcasttest";
    BroadcastReceiver broadcaster;
    BroadcastReceiver broadreciever;
    Intent intent;
    Handler handler;
    WebSocketClient client;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        intent=new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        handler=new Handler();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// Let it continue running until it is stopped.
         ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        try {
            client = new WebSocketClient(new URI(
                    "ws://xxxxxxx-xxxx.rhcloud.com:8000/browser")) {

                @Override
                 public void onOpen(ServerHandshake handshakedata) {
                    Log.d("1", "open");
                    status = true;

                }

                @Override
                public void onMessage(String message) {


                    Log.d("reply", message);
                    intent.putExtra("msg", message);
                    sendBroadcast(intent);

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception ex) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onClose(int code, String reason, boolean remote{
                    status = false;

                }
            };




        }catch(Exception e){


        }
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        return START_STICKY;
    }




    private Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            client.connect();

            for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
                if(status){
                    intent.putExtra("msg","open");
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                    break;
                }else{
                    try {
                        intent.putExtra("msg",client.getReadyState().toString());
                        sendBroadcast(intent);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!status) {
                intent.putExtra("msg","Time Out");
                sendBroadcast(intent);

            }



        }
    };





    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I am calling the start service method in Main Activity from a button click event. The output is always turned quickly to Closing and finally shows as Timed out. I wonder what could be the reason?

Comment: I suppose you have internet connection so webSocket client is not responding properly Android has many websocket clients which one ur using ?

Comment: No my internet connection is working fine. I have used Java-Websocket-1.3.jar file in my project. Is it wrong? I am new to use websockets in android.

Comment: You should check your server implementation as sockets are highly dependent on the underlying protocol which if different leads to connection timeout checkout my answer below its a tested client they have code samples just add that and it works

Comment: did you able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The websocket client ur using is not that robust try using Engine IO client which i used for my project , great performance 
https://github.com/nkzawa/engine.io-client.java
Not all clients are compatible with your server check what is being used on Server and that connection should be replicated using different library on server and client leads to breaking of connections

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll try it now.